# Automatically switch buffer when opening NERDTree on vim open

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Currently I have NERDTree opening by default when I edit a file that is not a git commit message using this command:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if &filetype !=# 'gitcommit' | NERDTree | endif
```

Only issue is that when the file opens, NERDTree is the default buffer, which is very annoying. What can I add to my vimrc file so that when I open a file, that file is the focused buffer, and not NERDTree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this command to switch to the previous window after NERDTree is opened.

```
autocmd VimEnter * if &filetype !=# 'gitcommit' | NERDTree | wincmd p | endif
```

Answer (score 2):

[nerdtree tabs](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs) will handle that for you automatically.

```
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup=1
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_gui_startup=1
```

It will also select the right buffer for you.